# Make GET request with auth header

Tags: html, http

I'm trying to refactor a xhr call to a different domain to something a little more portable(works only in ie if you change settings)

It's a GET request with AUTH header I want to make. There can be no user input. So far I've tried.

```
<a href="http://user:pass@domain">test</a> --- won't work in ie. Works in chrome
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=http://user:pass@domain">  --- won't work in ie. Only works in chrome
```

Today it uses setRequestHeader on XMLHttpRequest. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

[Internet Explorer does not support user names and passwords in Web site addresses](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489/EN-US)

> By default, versions of Windows Internet Explorer that were released
>   starting with the release of security update 832894 do not support
>   handling user names and passwords in HTTP and HTTP with Secure Sockets
>   Layer (SSL) or HTTPS URLs. The following URL syntax is not supported
>   in Internet Explorer or in Windows Explorer:
>
> ```
> http(s)://username:password@server/resource.ext
> ```

there are also some "Workarounds for application and Web site developers" that should help you solving your problem.

also, theres a [fix (download-link)](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9767718) that disabled this new default behavior again.

Comment: I don't see any workarounds that would work in the browser. Am I wrong?